# How to use TFX with Google colab?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-extended

[image]

How to use TFX with Google Colab?  We are trying to run TFX in Colab with reference to the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/tutorials/tfx/penguin_simple?hl=ja).  Actually, I have installed it with pip as per the documentation, but the error occurs as shown in the picture.  If anyone can help me to solve this problem, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi there, can you please share your error message as the plain text format

Comment: Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting tfx
  Downloading tfx-0.23.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.7/1.7 MB 42.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting absl-py<0.9,>=0.7 (from tfx)
  Downloading absl-py-0.8.1.tar.gz (103 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 103.2/103.2 kB 11.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

Comment: note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.